# What alternative to bitmap for network connectivity check?

Tags: algorithm, fortran, nodes, lookup

I have a set of nodes, each identified by a unique integer (UID), which are arranged into one or more networks. Each network has one or more root nodes. I need to know which nodes are not connected to any root nodes.

At present, from a previous product iteration, my connectivity check starts at each root node and follows all connections. For every found node, a bit in a bitmap is set so that you can quickly check if a node has already been found / processed. Once all paths for all root nodes have been followed, the complete set of nodes is compared against the 'found' bitmap to show all the unconnected nodes.

Previously, UIDs were sequential and I could consolidate them to remove gaps. So using the first ID as an offset, I just made my found array quite large and indexed found nodes into the bitmap directly using the UID (i.e., if I found node 1000, I'd set the 1000th bit in the bitmap). However, with the current version of the product, I have less control over the node UIDs. I can't consolidate them, and third party interaction is unpredictably making very large gaps (e.g., UIDs might jump from being in the thousands to being in the tens of millions). I have come across instances where my bitmap array is too small to accommodate the gaps and the connectivity check fails.

Now, I could just go on increasing the size of my bitmap array, but that always runs the risk of still being too small and is not very resource efficient. Thus, I'm looking to replace it with something else. Obviously, I'd like it to be as fast and as resource efficient as possible - I think some sort of hashed map is what I need. Unfortunately, I have to make this work in Fortran, so I don't have access to <map> etc.

What is the best way to hash my UIDs into a lookup structure, such that I can easily check if I already found that node?

Comment: I guess FORTRAN 95? (Although some of my code is still F77!)

Comment: So it is Fortran and not FORTRAN then...

Comment: Yeah, Intel Visual Fortran circa 2011

Comment: Is this as 'simple' as hashing my UIDs to the size of my bitmap? I'm very unlikely to have 2 million UIDs to deal with...

Comment: It is not that simple because several UIDs might have the same hash (this is called a collision, see also janneb's answer) and you need to handle this case in the hash map. An alternative is to use `iso_c_binding` and use C++'s `std::map`.

Comment: Instead of using a hash, could you use a B-tree?  It is faster than a hash when there are vast amounts of data and the performance is always the same regardless of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the node types themselves, you could add a `found` field, and use that?

If that is not possible, then yes, a hash table sounds like the obvious solution. Depending on how the UID's are distributed, you might get away with something as simple as `mod(UID, bitmap_size)`. But, you still need to handle collisions somehow. There's lot of literature on that topic, so I won't go into that here, except to note that robinhood hashing is pretty cool (except maybe a bit complicated for a one-off use).

Comment: Reading around - can you only make a Perfect Hash or Minimal Perfect Hash with a predefined set of input pairs?

Comment: @Kyudos: Indeed, in perfect hashing, in order to construct the hash function you need the set of input keys.